# Deleting previous features in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, geometry, delete

I need a hand, I'm stuck on [this](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/measure.html) example. I want to understand how it's possible to delete a previous feature.

Comment: the example is little bit complex because it has draw interaction and create tooltip with drawstart/drawend event. you can start from adding draw interaction and find how to get line feature from map.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this piece of code that get features one by one and delete them and also  the tip elements

```
      function clear(){
      var features = source.getFeatures();
 if (features != null && features.length > 0) {
     for (var x in features) {
        var properties = features[x].getProperties();
        console.log(properties);
        var id = properties.id;
        if (id == selectedFeatureID) {
          source.removeFeature(features[x]);  
           break;
        }
      }
    } 
    }
```

and then call this function to clear the features and and add this to delete the tip elements

```
       document.getElementById('foo').onclick =  function abc()
         {  
                     clear();
 for(var i = document.getElementsByClassName("tooltip-static").length ; i > 0 ; i=i-1)
               {
           var staticTooltip = document.getElementsByClassName("tooltip-static")[0];
         if (staticTooltip) {
              staticTooltip.parentNode.removeChild(staticTooltip);
         createMeasureTooltip(); 
          }        
            }
              }
```